# Nginx PHP error_page Downloading/ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Tags: php, nginx

I am working to have `error_page` direct to PHP pages, but for some reason these pages are not working properly. I've done some research and haven't been able to find anyone with this exact problem, or anything that fixes it.

For example, let's say I have the following file structure:

```
/discord
-- /error
---- 404.php
---- test.php
```

`test.php` executes fine, while `404.php` does not. If I go into my Nginx configuration and swap the 404 error page from `404.php` to `test.php`, the result swaps too. `test.php` doesn't work properly and `404.php` works fine. It is important to note that with HTML error pages, this works perfectly fine.

Now, by "not working properly," I mean that the server either doesn't respond at all, or the file literally downloads to my computer (PHP code and all). If I try to visit a page that would generate one of these errors, I get the Chrome error `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`:
[image: Showcase of response, according to Chrome]

On the other hand, if I visit the page directly (i.e. `/discord/error/404.php`) in my browser, the file downloads. It seems like there have been some scenarios where visiting a page that generates the error also downloads it, but I could be mistaken, as I cannot remember how to replicate that.

Here is my configuration for the `/discord` alias:

```
location /discord {
        alias /var/karaoke/discord/www/html;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /discord/error/404.php;

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

        }

        error_page 404 /discord/error/404.php;
            location = /discord/error/404.php {
        }
        error_page 403 /discord/error/403.php;
            location = /discord/error/403.php {
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /discord/error/50x.php;
            location = /discord/error/50x.php {
        }
    }
```

It's hard to remember and list everything I've tried, but here's some of them:

- `try_files $rui /discord/error/404.php` in the `~ \.php$` location block
- `recursive_error_pages` in the beginning of the `~ \.php$` location block
- Disabling `fastcgi_intercept_errors`
- Moving the `~ \.php$` location block before and after the `error_page` definitions.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `location = /discord/error/404.php {
        }` will cause the file to be downloaded. You should not have these blocks. You want them to be processed as php files

Comment: Thank you, that worked! If you leave your answer as an official answer then I'll gladly accept it.